# Paste side by side multiple files by numerical order

Tags: shell, paste

I have many files in a directory with similar file names like file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, ..... , file1000. They are of the same dimension, and each one of them has 5 columns and 2000 lines. I want to paste them all together side by side in a numerical order into one large file, so the final large file should have 5000 columns and 2000 lines.

I tried

```
for x in $(seq 1 1000); do 
paste `echo -n "file$x "` > largefile
done
```

Instead of writing all file names in the command line, is there a way I can paste those files in a numerical order (file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, ..., file10, file11, ..., file1000)?

for example:

file1

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1
...
```

file2

```
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 
....
```

file 3

```
3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3
....
```

paste file1 file2 file3 .... file 1000 > largefile

largefile

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
....
```

Thanks.

Comment: reanme the files an put leading 0s in would sort that out

Comment: I realized I may not be able to use paste * > largefile in my command line since after previous steps, there are other files in the same directory. I have have to deal with files with specific names like "file$n" only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your current shell is bash: `paste -d " " file{1..1000}`

Comment: _`bash`_ or `zsh` or `ksh93`. That syntax originated in `zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

you need rename the files with leading zeroes, like

```
paste <(ls -1 file* | sort -te -k2.1n) <(seq -f "file%04g" 1000) | xargs -n2 echo mv
```

The above is for "dry run" - Remove the `echo` if you satisfied...

or you can use e.g. perl

```
ls file* | perl -nlE 'm/file(\d+)/; rename $_, sprintf("file%04d", $1);'
```

and after you can

```
paste file*
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
paste -d ' ' file<->(n)
```

`<x-y>` is to match positive decimal integer numbers from `x` to `y`. `x` and/or `y` can be omitted so `<->` is any positive decimal integer number. It could also be written `[0-9]##` (`##` being the `zsh` equivalent of regex `+`).

The `(n)` is the *globbing qualifiers*. The `n` globbing qualifier turns on numeric sorting which sorts on all sequences of decimal digits appearing in the file names.