# Awk print entire column based on only one row element fulfilling condition

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

I have a list of files containing some measurements and I would like to compile them into a single file. If the second column contains on any row numerical data (or it does not contain NaN's on every row of the column), the entire file should be pasted into the master file (bar) on new columns.

```
File1    File2    File3    Expected_Output   Actual_Output
1  4     1 NaN    1 NaN         1  4              1  4   
2  5     2  7     2 NaN         2  5              2  5
3  6     3  8     3 Nan         3  6              3  6
                                1 NaN                 
                                2  7                  
                                3  8
```

My code currently rejects all the files that have even one NaN on the second column.

```
for foo in *; do cat $foo | awk '{if ($2 ~ /[0-9]/) print $0}' >> bar ;done
```

Comment: So you have a set of files. Given one of them, if any of the 2nd fields is a number, the entire file should be pasted to master. Do you want to paste them one after the other (`cat file1 >> master; cat file2 >> master`) or one next to the other? Some [mcve] would clarify the question.

Comment: I would like them to be pasted one next to the other. I was using paste before to do that, but now the number of files that I have as input is too large and therefore I have to reject the files without measurements (most of the files actually). They are separate issues. Should I just separate the issues in the question above, for clarity?

Comment: Yes, I think it is best, for clarity. Regarding pasting multiple files one next to the other, you can refer to [Paste side by side multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17075524/1983854).

Comment: @mannaroth: Post your question with a minimal verifiable input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this, in bash and awk:

```
for f in files*; 
do 
    if awk '$2 ~ /[0-9]/{exit 1}' $f   # awk to detect numeric value, return 1 when
    then                               # above, consider /^[0-9]*$/ or such, see comments
        echo 1                         # no need for this, so use :
    else 
        echo 0                         # cat $f >> masterfile.txt
    fi 
done
```

ie. awk is only used for detecting if there is even a single numeric value in `$2` and if there is, awk exits with exit code 1, which is used in bash to detect a positive match. By default awk exits with code 0.

Comment: Nice! Probably worth saying `/^[0-9]*$/`, although _the second column contains on any row numerical data_ is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @fedorqui I know but I did the unforgiveable and read OPs code. ;D

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you, this solves my problem. However, you might want to edit the answer, "# cat $f >> masterfile.txt" should replace the "# no need for else" comment.